# Firing a function AFTER redirect

Tags: hooks, redirect, login, errors, wp-redirect

I am using a function that redirects the user to a custom page, rather than wp-login in the event of errors. In my case I am using the Http Referer function to send the user back to the same page because I have the login form in a modal. How can I execute a function on the redirected page, so that the page automatically opens the modal?

This is the code for the redirect in the event of an error:

```
add_filter('login_redirect', '_catch_login_error', 10, 3);
function _catch_login_error($redir1, $redir2, $wperr_user) {
    $rurl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if(!is_wp_error($wperr_user) || !$wperr_user->get_error_code()) return $redir1;
        switch($wperr_user->get_error_code()) {
            case 'incorrect_password': 
            case 'empty_password': 
            case 'invalid_username': 
            default: wp_redirect($rurl); }
        return $redir1;
     }
```

This code courtesy of http://projectivemotion.com/2011/12/16/redirect-failed-login-attempt-wordpress/#comment-653

The function I want to execute after redirect is:

```
add_action('genesis_before_post', 'force_open_modal_1');
function force_open_modal_1() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#loginmodal').reveal();
    });
    </script>
<?php }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Try `add_query_arg( 'key', 'value' );` - then hook into `wp_query()` with your fn, and switch with `get_arg( 'key' )` if you want to trigger or abort.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how do I go about hooking the _catch_login_error into a wp_query? I'm a little confused

Comment: Not "a" wp_query. Into the equally named hook (or maybe into `template_redirect` or whatever fits).

Answer (score 1):

Add a [nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces#Adding_a_nonce_to_a_URL) to your redirect url.

See the examples in the codex for [`wp_nonce_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_url#Examples). Use [`wp_verify_nonce()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce) to check for the nonce and run your function to load the modal.

You might also want to check if [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) in this case.